# My app crashes on ACTION VIEW in samsung devices But it Works on any other brand

Tags: android

The app works on other devices but not Samsung j200

error comes from this code :

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
  Uri.parse("geo:" + mission.Customer.Lat + "," + mission.Customer.Lng)); 
  startActivity(intent);
```

Any solutions

Comment: Probably the Samsung j200 doesn't have an appropriate viewer for `geo:` Uris. Try adding a null check for your intent before starting the activity.

Comment: I did it, thx @oemel09

Answer (score 0):

When starting an activity with implicit use the code below to check if there is a package with an activity that matches the given criteria.

```
  if( intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)  != null )
      {
        startActivity(intent)
      }
```